# Store Java 8 Instant as MySQL Int (Not Timestamp)

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, java-8

In my application, I'd like to store the epoch time for some columns, as the application will be used in multiple timezones, and I'd like to avoid DST etc.

I've been using the other new time classes in Java 8 happily to represent DateTime etc. However, I discovered when validating my schema that Instant expects the Timestamp type, instead of INT.

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [lastMessageSeenAt] in table [groupchatmember]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [datetime (Types#TIMESTAMP)]]
```

Given that timestamps are an extra byte, and only range up to 2038, I'd rather use INT.

Is there a way to tell hibernate to use INT for Instant?

#### MySQL Column Definition:

```
lastMessageSeenAt INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

#### JPA Field Definition:

```
@Column(name = "lastMessageSeenAt")
private Instant lastMessageSeenAt = Instant.MIN;
```

Comment: The error message seems to be saying that the column in the underlying table is `datetime`, not something else.  You should use some kind of integer type to store an epoch UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've declared the column as `lastMessageSeenAt INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ` in the schema. The field in the JPA entity is a Java 8 Instant. Isn't Instant just an integer underneath anyway?

Comment: How about you show us the code?  The table definition, the relevant java and the relevant sql?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A JDBC (and standard SQL) `Timestamp` is not the same as a MySQL `TIMESTAMP` type.

Comment: @MatBailie add those details.

Comment: why don't you use int type instead of Instant for "lastMessageSeenAt" variable and set it by (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) which is an int value?

Comment: @epcpu I could use int in the JPA entities, but then I would have to constantly convert between the two, which doesn't seem like a clean solution. I'm currently working on using JPA Attribute Converters for a solution.